# Создать файл bat который

Tags: сортировка, cmd, командная-строка

в который записать все  активные процессы в ОС, сгруппировать по имени и отсортировать в рамках группы по размеру используемой памяти.

Не получается сделать последний пункт. Сортируется либо по памяти, либо по названию

```
   tasklist | sort /+1 /+64
```

Comment: Не дублируйте вопросы. | Вам нужно начать с группировки. Сортировка делается после.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  не подскажите как сделать группировку?

Comment: Я не знаю, как это сделать в батнике. Поэтому предлагаю PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку tasklist выводит данные в виде таблицы с фиксированными полями. Лучше воспользоваться выводом данных в формате CSV:

```
tasklist /nh /fo CSV
```

Но вообще-то подобный вопрос уже задавался. И там решение было реализовано на утилите wmic:

[list sorted by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578513/can-a-wmic-processes-table-within-the-command-prompt-window-be-sorted-by-a-val)

Минус решения - сортировка по имени процессов частичная: